# Looping through a dictionary to get values

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a dict I am working with and I would like to loop through it and pull the value(s) for 'network' under both 'process-id' and process-id-vrf'. I cant seem to get it to pull both, only one or the other. Can someone give me some advice on how to make this work. Here is the output from ospf_protocol.items() so you can see the structure.

```
dict_items([('process-id', [{'id': 2, 'area': [{'area-id': 0, 'authentication': {'message-digest': [None]}}], 'network': [{'ip': '192.168.200.0', 'wildcard': '0.0.0.255', 'area': 0}]}]), ('process-id-vrf', [{'id': 1, 'vrf': 'army', 'area': [{'area-id': 0, 'authentication': {'message-digest': [None]}}], 'network': [{'ip': '192.1.1.1', 'wildcard': '0.0.0.0', 'area': 0}, {'ip': '192.168.100.1', 'wildcard': '0.0.0.0', 'area': 0}], 'router-id': '192.1.1.1'}])])



    for network_statement in ospf_protocol['process-id'] or ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf']:
        for ospf_network in network_statement['network']:
            ospf_interface = ospf_network['ip']
            ospf_wildcard = ospf_network['wildcard']
            # determine netmask and network address for valid ospf enabled interfaces
            wildcard_to_mask = str(ipaddress.ip_network(ospf_interface+'/'+ospf_wildcard, strict=False).netmask)
            if wildcard_to_mask == '0.0.0.0':
                wildcard_to_mask = '255.255.255.255'
                ospf_int_range = ipaddress.ip_interface(ospf_interface+'/'+wildcard_to_mask)
            else:
                ospf_int_range = ipaddress.ip_interface(ospf_interface+'/'+wildcard_to_mask)
```

Comment: You can use '+' instead of 'or' to concatenate two list (the one under 'process-id' and the one 'under process-id-vrf')

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first things first:

1/ Python objects all have a truth value in a boolean context. For the builtin types, numerical zero, empty containers and the empty string are all false.

2/ the logical operators 'and' and 'or' don't return a boolean value, but for 'and' the last operand if both are true else the second operand, for 'or' the first operand that is not false, else the last operand.

So this:

```
in ospf_protocol['process-id'] or ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf']
```

doesn't do what you expect - it **first** evaluates `ospf_protocol['process-id'] or ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf']`, and return the first of those object that is not empty (or the last one if both are empty).

Now your code snippet isn't a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we don't know for sure what types are `ospf_protocol['process-id']` and `ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf']` - but assuming they are lists of dicts, you can

1/ concatenate them:

```
all_processes = ospf_protocol['process-id'] +  ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf']
for item in all_processes:
    print(item)
```

2/ use `itertools.chain()` to avoid building a new list (only of interest if those lists are huge):

```
import itertools
all_protocols = itertools.chain(ospf_protocol['process-id'],  ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf']) 
for item in all_protocols:
    print(item)
```

3/ or quite simply add a first `for` loop iterating over a `tuple` made of both ie:

```
for processe in (ospf_protocol['process-id'],  ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf']):
    for item in processes:
        print(item)
```

I can't of course garantee the result since, well, I don't *really* know for sure what your data look like, but you can't put the blame on me for this ;-)

Answer (score -2):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to you do not need to loop over the dict.
More like `ospf_protocol['process-id']['network']` and `ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf']['network']`

Comment: I basically have two routing processes on a device and I am trying to pull the all the network statements from both processes so that I can compare them to interfaces and determine which are participating in that routing protocol. I tried 'and' and it doesn't seem to pull both.

Comment: So just use + to concat two dicts like Don said

Comment: I tried to do that and I am not clear how to get all the values from network. I still get only one process. Sorry extremely new to python. I tried to convert it back from a list to a dict so I could look at the keys but it gives me: 
  File "testbed.py", line 64, in routingrule
    ospf_test = dict(ospf_protocol['process-id'] + ospf_protocol['process-id-vrf'])
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required